# DolphinScheduler is deployed through kubernetes, how do I configure ldap, values.yaml?

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

I deployed DolphinScheduler through kubernetes with reference to the document. There is a configuration file values.yaml. I want to refer to the ldap configuration but I don't know where it is. Is it in another configuration file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I built it based on the official image. For example, if I want to configure mysql related configuration, I can configure it in the values.yaml configuration file, but I can't find where to configure it if I want to configure ldap-based configuration.